# Loading class in Jenkins : No such property for class

Tags: class, jenkins

i'm trying to load a class file in my Jenkins Pipeline. Here's the code :

---

```
pipeline{
agent none
stages{
    stage('TESTCLASS'){
        agent{
            label 'testSlave'
        }
        steps{
            script{

                def cl = load 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\testClass.Groovy'
                def b = cl.B
                echo b.greet("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's my class file :

---

```
class A{
  def greet(name){
    return "greet from A: $name!"
  }
}
class B{
  def greet(name){
    return "greet from B: $name!"
  }
}
// this method just to have nice access to create class by name
Object getProperty(String name){
   return this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(name).newInstance();
} 

return this
```

---

When I build the pipeline, it gives me

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: B for class...

---

Someone knows why? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with: def b = cl.getProperty('B') !